# org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: move target out of bounds

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am passing input to rich text field. For that I have written the code below:

```
public void inputToDescriptionField() throws InterruptedException   , AWTException
{
    
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(descriptionField));
    Actions a = new Actions(driver);
    a.moveToElement(descriptionField).click().build().perform();        

    Robot r = new Robot();
    String text = "Program Description";
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(text);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
     clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);
        
       r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
       r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
       r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
       r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

but I am getting the error move target out of bounds

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the HTML of the rich text field? The target out of bounds error suggests that there could be an issue with the element's availability.

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

```
"org.openqa.selenium.interactions.
MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: 
move target out of bounds"
```

typically occurs when the target element is not visible or outside the visible area of the screen. Here are some possible solutions to try:

1 Scroll to the element: If the element is not visible, you can try scrolling to it using the `scrollIntoView` method. For example:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", descriptionField);
```

2 Use an offset: If the element is partially hidden or overlapped by another element, you can try using an offset to move the mouse pointer slightly away from the center of the element. For example:

```
Actions a = new Actions(driver);
a.moveToElement(descriptionField, 5, 5).click().build().perform();
```

3 Use a different approach: Instead of using `Actions` and `Robot` to simulate typing, you can try using the `sendKeys` method to directly send the text to the element. For example:

```
descriptionField.sendKeys("Program Description");
```

4 Check if the element is present: Before performing any actions on the element, you can check if the element is present in the DOM using `ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated`. For example:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("descriptionField")));
```

It's also possible that the error is caused by a bug in Selenium or the browser driver. In that case, you can try updating to the latest version of Selenium and the browser driver, or using a different browser or driver.